# Find the group of units of the monoid power-set(a), where a is a non-empty set

Tags: abstract-algebra

Find the group of units of the monoid power-set(a), where a is a non-empty set

This is finding the units within the ring right?

Answer (score 1):

it depends on which monoid you really want to study for a set A:

- with multiplication $\cap$ the only unit is $A$
- with multiplication $\cup$ the only unit is $\emptyset$
- with multiplication = symmetric difference all elements are self-invers
- if you start with a monoid $A$ and equipp $P(A)$ with the complex product $XY:=\{ xy\mid x\in X, y\in Y \}$ then the singletons $\{ m \}$ are the units where $m$ is a unit of $M$. So the group of units is isomorphic to that of $M$.